# Edit new field string visible in significant Terms on kibana 4.1

Tags: field, kibana

I need create (kibana 4.1) a new dynamique field (string) for use in graph with 'significant terms'

How write equivalent SQL script on kibana interface or E.S ?

Exemple MSSQL:

> Select reason_txt, response_txt, 
>         (CASE WHEN reason_txt='none' THEN response_txt else reason_txt end) as newfield

thanks you very much